# Are there any freeware LPR (License plate recogniser) software in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ocr, lpr

Are there any freeware LPR (License plate recogniser) libraries or software in .net ?

Also can you list the freeware OCR libraries and software avaliable in .net ?

Comment: What did your search turn up?

Comment: Java ANPR... but i am looking for .net based.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question.  In fact I think many thousands would be interested in this software.  The question is quite clear on what it is asking.  My house is in a cul-de-sac. If I could run this software on the images captured by my home security camera and I would be able to give an alarm rightaway if a stranger's car come to this place more than once.

Comment: Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It's open source, free and does a great job recognizing plates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [emgu.cv](http://www.emgu.com).  It's an open source wrapper for opencv, an open source image analysis tool.  [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp) is an example on how to use it to detect license plates.

My experience is fairly positive as for this just working. It catches the main cases 90% of the time or so I'd say.

Comment: Is this having a stable version ?

Comment: I've had no problems with stability with this.  They don't specifically list it as stable, but they seem to list the alpha versions as alpha.

Comment: @DanTheMan Its Mobile version is not free!

Comment: @HotTester:its mobile version is not free,did you buy it?

Comment: @DanTheMan Copying the code from that website just gives me loads of errors, including stuff like `'OcrEngineMode' does not contain a definition for 'TesseractCubeCombined'` - which makes it seem like the code is just wrong, as that property does not exist... Please can you assist?